# jQuery File Upload doesn't saves the filename, but other

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, filenames, jquery-file-upload

I want to upload an image to a local directory on my localhost. This is what I do:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    add: function (e, data) {
        $("#submitentity").on('click', function () {
            data.submit();
        });
    },
    done: function (e, data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

As you can see when the upload is done I log the data. The results is the objects (files) :

```
files: Array[1]
   0: File
       lastModifiedDate: Fri Aug 30 2013 11:00:12 GMT+0200 (CEST)
       name: "Woof.gif"
       size: 1820
       type: "image/gif"
       webkitRelativePath: ""
```

As you can see the name of the file is `"Woo.gif"`. But when I check in my upload folder, the image is saved BUT the filename is changed to `"52c87669bbfe0.gif"`. How does this come?

My upload file in view:

```
<input class="form-control" id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="{{ oneup_uploader_endpoint('gallery') }}" multiple />
```

I use the jquery file upload plugin that can be found [here](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/).

Comment: Please share the code you used to save your file to the directory

Comment: That is the code .. I use the jquery file upload. Basic implementation here https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin

Comment: Some code on the server (I assume PHP) must be executed to save the file. that's what you should store.  My guess is that there's an error there that's causing the wrong file name to be stored.

Comment: Check the link in my commenct, no server-side code needed..

Comment: there is a form action before the input file control. where is its action (php) file?

Comment: Do you use a server side framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the [oneupuploaderbundle](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle) from Symfony2 and they create the name in the file named `'UniqidNamer.php'`. The original code is:

```
<?php

 namespace Oneup\UploaderBundle\Uploader\Naming;

 use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Uploader\File\FileInterface;

 class UniqidNamer implements NamerInterface
 {
     public function name(FileInterface $file)
     {
        return sprintf('%s.%s', uniqid(), $file->getExtension());
     }
 }
```

I changed to my own filename settings.

Comment: I hope you didn't change the original source code as you can register your own file namer by registering it in the configuration. https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/custom_namer.md

Comment: Yes indeed, I used a custom namer.